# Matlab: Using surf within a uipanel

Tags: matlab, graph, figure, geometry-surface

I have a 2d matrix containing 4 possible different values.
I've used surf to display it as a like a chess board which works fine.

Now i'm building a UI for my project (w/o GUIDE) and I'm trying to set a parent for the surf
in one of the uipanel I have (with a handle) I get:

```
"An object of class surface, can not be a child of class figure"
```

How can I implement such a thing? (Or something similar).
Oh, and the input of the surf in the matrix.

Thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 0):

I've uploaded the project to git:

https://github.com/guywald/allele_fixation